# What approach should I use in PostGIS to find all services that have a radius that intersect a customer

Tags: postgis

I'm new to PostGIS and looking for suggestions on a reasonable approach to solve the following problem. I have services that have a lat/lng and service radius (an area that the service is available in). I have customers that just have a lat/lng. I'd like to setup up a table(s) that support indexed queries that return all services that have a service areas where the users location is contained.

```
Service
- latitude
- longitude
- radius
- type
```

```
Customer
- latitude
- longitude
```

- Bonus points if the query is easy to extend to filter services by other attributes as well *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and index **geography** columns in both tables, then you can make use of [ST_DWITHIN()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) which makes use of the indexes

```
SELECT service.*
FROM service
JOIN customer
 ON ST_DWITHIN(service.geog, customer.geom, service.radius)
WHERE customer.id=123
 AND service.type='abc';
```